# Shoud I upgrade to Safari 6.1?

Tags: safari, upgrade

I have a Lion machine and a Mountain Lion machine. Software Update has offered to upgrade Safari from 6.0.5 to 6.1 on both machines. Is this upgrade worth it? Any issues or glitches? I didn't find any comments on this upgrade on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to latest software version is *generally* a good idea for security and performance reasons.

Specifically Safari 6.1 brings its lot of security fixes: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6000?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US.

In terms of functionalities, Safari 6.1 brings the following:

- Shared Links: See links shared by people you follow on Twitter;
- New sidebar (Reading List, Bookmarks and Shared Links to the left of the browser; can be hidden);
- One-click bookmarking;
- (Performance enhancements) Safari Power Saver: Only play content from accepted plug-ins;

See more here: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/10/22/apple-releases-safari-6-1-for-mountain-lion-with-shared-links-new-sidebar-power-saver-and-more/.

Whether you should upgrade to Safari 6.1 is up to you. I recommend you do.

Comment: I did upgrade and I’ve had no problems.